# What does this error mean? WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away]

Tags: errors

WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away]

I did not make any changes, and the host says that there is no problem with MySQL. Can anyone explain what the error means? and how to troubleshoot?

This is a shared hosting environment, and no recent changes where made to the site. Also other wordpress sites are encountering the issue with this same shared server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a WordPress error, it is [from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html):

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

Talk with your host again.

Comment: Thanks, lousy host. I had never seen that error before though.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your host and consider finding a new host; it's not that difficult to run a MySQL server.

From wordpress.org: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)

Comment: Well, definitely DO NOT use Liquidweb as a host.   I've been a *nix sysadmin for 20+ years and they are still fighting with me saying it is a script error.   Really?   12 different plugins, a theme, Jetpack, WordPress core.  All buggy to the point of failing regularly?

Sad part is I know it is a MySQL config/server load problem and they keep saying "no errors in the main message log".  Obviously they don't know how to monitor a MySQL server even after I sent them several URLs on the topic.

Sadly I am now planning 2 days to move to a dedicated server far away from Liquidweb.   So aggravating!

Comment: Liquidweb is not a WordPress-recommended host.

Comment: I know.  I had been using them for years.   I can't continue to recommend them at this point after several server crashes and now a mismanaged database.   That said, there are some very good WordPress friendly hosts that are not on the WordPress-recommended list.  However, after reviewing that link I may well go with one of the 3 that are on there now.     Thanks for posting that URL.